# Using MaxPool1D on inputs with 4 dimensions (4D tensor)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to create a NN architecture for multiple instance learning, so the instances are actually bags of of time series segments. I would like to do COnv1D and MaxPool1D over the features (last dimension), I specify input as having 4 dimensions and that works fine for Conv1D but throws an error with MaxPool1D:

```
n = 6
sample_size = 300
code_size = 50
learning_rate = 0.001
bag_size = None

# autoencoder: n_bags X bag_size X n_samples (timesteps) X n_measurements
input_window = Input(shape=(bag_size,sample_size, n)) 
x = Conv1D(filters=40, kernel_size=21, activation='relu', padding='valid')(input_window)
x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(x)
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer max_pooling1d_4 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, None, 280, 40]
```

According to [TF documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.4/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MaxPool1D?hl=en)
MaxPool1D only works on 3D tensors.
Is there a work-around?

Comment: What dimension are you trying to apply the pooling over? the last one? or the second last one?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal for each feature over time. Which works just right with 3D tensor and 1D Conv and MaxPool

Comment: Do check if my answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: glad to help cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's not clear on which axis you are trying to pool over, you could use the `MaxPooling2D` with the right pooling size, which IIUC in this case would be `(1,2)`

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model

n = 6
sample_size = 300
code_size = 50
learning_rate = 0.001
n_bags= None

# autoencoder: n_bags X n_instances_in_bag X n_samples (timesteps) X n_measurements
input_window = layers.Input(shape=(n_bags,sample_size, n)) 
x = layers.Conv1D(filters=40, kernel_size=21, activation='relu', padding='valid')(input_window)

x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2))(x)

model = Model(input_window, x)

model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         [(None, None, 300, 6)]    0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_3 (Conv1D)            (None, None, 280, 40)     5080      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, None, 140, 40)     0         
=================================================================
Total params: 5,080
Trainable params: 5,080
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```